# How to generate objects with the same type in Hilt?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-jetpack, dagger-hilt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("http://example.com/")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideMyRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("http:/my.com/")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }
}
```

Their difference is only `baseUrl`.

---

I tried to solve this problem by use `@Qualifier`.

```
interface RetrofitQualifier {
    @Qualifier
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
    annotation class Retrofit

    @Qualifier
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
    annotation class MyRetrofit
}
```

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @RetrofitQualifier.Retrofit
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("http://example.com/")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @RetrofitQualifier.MyRetrofit
    fun provideMyRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("http:/my.com/")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }
}
```

---

And I use it by use `@RetrofitQualifier.MyRetrofit` in my class:

```
class MyRepository @Inject constructor(
    application: Application
)  {

    ...    

    @Inject
    @RetrofitQualifier.MyRetrofit
    lateinit var  retrofit:Retrofit


    private val service: Service = retrofit.create(Service::class.java)

    ...

    }
```

However, I was failed, the log is

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property retrofit has not been initialized
```

What should  I do? Maybe use `@Named`? I am not sure...

Comment: could you please post your @InstallIn? to check if your repository is in the same installIn than your provides to your Retrofit?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Example with `Qualifier`, you can add this in the same file where you have your providers or even create a `RetrofitQualifier.kt` file and add them there.

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class RetrofitOne

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class RetrofitTwo
```

And the `@Provides`

```
@Singleton
@Provides
@RetrofitOne
fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl("http://example.com/")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
}

@Singleton
@Provides
@RetrofitTwo
fun provideMyRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl("http:/my.com/")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
}
```

Then in your `Repository` you can inject using two options

**Field injection**

```
// At field injection.
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyRepository @Inject constructor(...) {

  @RetrofitOne
  @Inject lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit
}
```

As a dependency injected-constructor class

```
// As a dependency of a constructor-injected class.
class MyRepository @Inject constructor(
  @RetrofitTwo private val retrofit: Retrofit
) : ...
```

But the thing is that perhaps you installedIn in another module where your Repository doesn't have visibility.

About the `@Named` you can still use it but as per the documentation is recommended to use `Qualifier`

Comment: Ok, I will add my @InstallIn immediately

Comment: Could it be another reason? Because when I have only one `Retrofit` and no `MyRetrofit`, it can run successfully.

Comment: Could you try using the inject-constructor way?

Comment: It's amazing. I succeeded! Why is that? Maybe you can feed this bug back to Google official? But I don't know how to operate. Thank you, you have helped me several times, thank you!

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS . I also face with is problem and I found this question. But I cant solve. Can you please help me SIR. this is my question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71121237/dagger-missing-binding-with-same-type-of-datastore