# Dagger missing binding with same type of DataStore

Tags: dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt

In my project, I have two `DataStore` ( better API of SharedPref ). I have `AuthDataStore` and `UserDataStore` with separate packages. I want to Inject those two DataStores in separate `repositories`. I used Dagger Hilt

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.40.5'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.40.5'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'
```

This is my DataStoreModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DsModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserDataStoreSource(
        ds: DataStore<Preferences>
    ): UserDataStoreSource {
        return UserDataStoreSourceImpl(ds = ds)
    }

    @Provides
    @Named(value = Constants.USER_DS_NAME)
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserDataStore(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ): DataStore<Preferences> {
        return PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create(
            produceFile = {
                context.preferencesDataStoreFile(Constants.USER_DS_NAME)
            }
        )
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthDataStoreSource(
        ds: DataStore<Preferences>
    ): AuthDataStore {
        return AuthDataStoreSourceImpl(ds = ds)
    }

    @Provides
    @Named(value = Constants.AUTH_DS_NAME)
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthDataStore(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ): DataStore<Preferences> {
        return PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create(
            produceFile = {
                context.preferencesDataStoreFile(Constants.AUTH_DS_NAME)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

This is my repositories.

```
open class AuthDataStoreSourceImpl @Inject constructor(
    @Named(value = Constants.AUTH_DS_NAME) private val ds: DataStore<Preferences>
) : AuthDataStore {

    companion object {
        val AUTH_STATE = booleanPreferencesKey("com.galaxytechno.auth_state")
    }

    override suspend fun putAuthFlag(isLoggedIn: Boolean) {
        ds.edit {
            it[AUTH_STATE] = isLoggedIn
        }
    }

    override suspend fun pullAuthFlag(): Flow<Boolean> {
        return ds.data
            .catch { exception ->
                if (exception is IOException) emit(emptyPreferences()) else throw exception

            }.map {
                it[AUTH_STATE] ?: false
            }
    }

}

open class UserDataStoreSourceImpl @Inject constructor(
    @Named(value = Constants.USER_DS_NAME) private val ds: DataStore<Preferences>
) : UserDataStoreSource {

    companion object {
        val ACCESS_TOKEN = stringPreferencesKey("com.galaxytechno.user.access_token")
        val REFRESH_TOKEN = stringPreferencesKey("com.galaxytechno.user.refresh_token")
    }

    override suspend fun putAccessToken(token: String) {
        ds.edit {
            it[ACCESS_TOKEN] = token
        }
    }

    override suspend fun pullAccessToken(): Flow<String> {
        return ds.data
            .catch { exception ->
                if (exception is IOException) emit(emptyPreferences()) else throw exception

            }
            .map {
                it[ACCESS_TOKEN] ?: "empty_access_token"
            }
    } }
```

These are my main repos:

```
class AuthRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val api: AuthApiService,
    @Named(value = Constants.AUTH_DS_NAME) private val ds: AuthDataStore,
    @Qualifier.Io private val io: CoroutineDispatcher
) : AuthRepository {
    override suspend fun login(
        mobileNumber: String,
        password: String
    ): Flow<RemoteResource<LoginDTO>> {
        return flow {
            emit(
                safeApiCall {
                    api.login(
                        mobileNumber = mobileNumber,
                        password = password
                    )
                }
            )
        }.flowOn(io)
    }

    override suspend fun putAuthFlag(isLoggedIn: Boolean) {
        withContext(io){
            ds.putAuthFlag(isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun pullAuthFlag(): Flow<Boolean> {
        return ds.pullAuthFlag()
    }
}

class UserRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val api: UserApiService,
    private val db: UserDatabase,
    @Named(value = Constants.USER_DS_NAME) private val ds : UserDataStoreSource,
    @Qualifier.Io private val io: CoroutineDispatcher
) : UserRepository {

}
```

This is my Repo module;

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserRepository(
        api: UserApiService,
        db: UserDatabase,
        @Named(value = Constants.USER_DS_NAME) ds : UserDataStoreSource,
        @Qualifier.Io io: CoroutineDispatcher
    ): UserRepository {
        return UserRepositoryImpl(
            api = api,
            db = db,
            ds = ds,
            io = io
        )
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthRepository(
        api: AuthApiService,
        @Named(value = Constants.AUTH_DS_NAME) ds: AuthDataStore,
        @Qualifier.Io io: CoroutineDispatcher
    ): AuthRepository {
        return AuthRepositoryImpl(
            api = api,
            ds = ds,
            io = io
        )
    }

}
```

*I have no idea with this. I read hilt documentation a lot. But I have lack of knowledge with Dagger. Please help me.*

My error :

```
D:\galaxy_techno\Chat\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\galaxytechno\chat\app\ChatApp_HiltComponents.java:140: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @javax.inject.Named("auth.chat.ds") com.galaxytechno.chat.auth.data.ds.AuthDataStore cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements ChatApp_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      @javax.inject.Named("auth.chat.ds") com.galaxytechno.chat.auth.data.ds.AuthDataStore is injected at
          com.galaxytechno.chat.app.di.RepositoryModule.provideAuthRepository(�, ds, �)
      com.galaxytechno.chat.auth.domain.repository.AuthRepository is injected at
          com.galaxytechno.chat.auth.domain.usecase.GetAuthStateUseCase(repo)
      com.galaxytechno.chat.auth.domain.usecase.GetAuthStateUseCase is injected at
          com.galaxytechno.chat.core.presentation.MainViewModel(getAuthStateUseCase)
      com.galaxytechno.chat.core.presentation.MainViewModel is injected at
          com.galaxytechno.chat.core.presentation.MainViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.galaxytechno.chat.app.ChatApp_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? com.galaxytechno.chat.app.ChatApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? com.galaxytechno.chat.app.ChatApp_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the `[Dagger/MissingBinding]` line, Dagger is looking for a `@Named("auth.chat.ds") AuthDataStore`. This means that you need an exact binding match, typically provided using `@Binds` or `@Provides`, including the exact class name, exact generics, and exact `@Qualifier` annotation (like `@Named`) with the exact same annotation values.

However, your DataStoreModule lists:

```kotlin
@Provides
@Singleton                                  // No @Named annotation
fun provideAuthDataStoreSource(
    ds: DataStore<Preferences>
): AuthDataStore {                          // AuthDataStore
    return /* ... */
}

@Provides
@Named(value = Constants.AUTH_DS_NAME)      // @Named("auth.chat.ds")
@Singleton
fun provideAuthDataStore(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context
): DataStore<Preferences> {                 // DataStore<Preferences>
    return /* ... */
}
```

So your parameter in `provideAuthModule`, `@Named(value = Constants.AUTH_DS_NAME) ds: AuthDataStore`, doesn't match. It's neither `@Named(AUTH_DS_NAME) DataStore<Preferences>` nor the unnamed/unqualified `AuthDataStore`.

Remove your `@Named` and you should be fine:

```kotlin
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideAuthRepository(
    api: AuthApiService,
    /* @Named(value = Constants.AUTH_DS_NAME) */ ds: AuthDataStore,
    /* ^-------------remove-----------------^ */
    @Qualifier.Io io: CoroutineDispatcher
): AuthRepository
```